# access service from host when ports and not linked

Tags: docker

When I link the exposed ports within container to the host port, everything works as expected...

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch

curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```

But when I do not use ports option with run command, I am not able to connect.

```
# docker run -d elasticsearch

# docker inspect 87c6bcb3b67e | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",

# curl -XGET 127.17.0.3:9200/_cat/indices
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.17.0.3 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I can log-in to container and access elasticsearch without any problem. like this...

```
# docker exec -it 2ec9026b755e bash

# curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```

Is there any way to access elasticsearch from host even if the ports are not linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to access elasticsearch from host even if the ports are not linked?

Normally no: that is what container are for: providing isolation. That allows you to launch many containers, each one running on the same port.

Comment: In that case I will protect the 9200 port of host and then link the ports as shown in the first example. will docker network come to my rescue?

Comment: docner network, especially in the latest 1.12 release, comes to your rescue in that it allows other containers on other machines to see/communicate with that first container. Other than that (for local host access) as long as your port is mapped to a host port, you are all set.